# TFS Source Control Explorer Expand [more]

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfvc

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with TFS 2012.  We are using local workspaces.

In Source Control Explorer under the Pending Change column I sometimes see "edit, [more]"
What this generally means is that I've edited the file and not yet checked in the change and also someone else has the file locked.

I can right-click the file and go to Advanced > Properties and see the name of the other user and what their status on the file is.  But I would like to see this information directly in the Source Control Explorer window.  It doesn't matter how wide I expand the column -- it always shows "[more]" rather than the actual information.

I've searched through the options but haven't found anything.  Is this just not possible in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, it is not possible to change this behaviour.

You could create a plugin for TFVC that did this for you with an additional column, but I would make a request on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com .